# Azure system status notifications filtering

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm using the Azure cloud and want to know about system incidents that effecting my product. So, I found their [system status page](https://status.dev.azure.com/). Since I'm doing the check from code (python), I don't want to crawl their HTML.

The only option I found is to use their [RSS feed](https://status.dev.azure.com/_rss).

Azure system has huge amount of services. None of them is not relevant for me, except for the Azure Storage product. I want to filter out all issues that not relevant to me.

Unfortunately, the RSS feed not containing information about the effected service.

Questions:

1. I'm wrong? How I can find the effected service in the RSS?
2. The RSS is the only option to get the information?

Thanks!

Comment: What information you want to get from azure storage?

Comment: I want to find a way to get notified only if Azure has an incident regarding this service. All the other - not relevant to me.

Comment: Is this what you want? Or still have other problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Azure Service Health REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resourcehealth/availabilitystatuses) to get the the service status. You could get the current availability statuses or list the historical availability statuses.

Also you could use the Azure Service Health in the Portal to stay informed about resource availability with resource health alerts. There is a tutorial about how to configure it:[Create activity log alerts on service notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/alerts-activity-log-service-notifications). You could configure the service you want to monitor.

And you could check the [current issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/service-health-overview#see-current-issues-which-impact-your-services) that are impacting your resources in the portal.

Comment: The `Azure service health` rest API is need authentication before pulling the information because of it specific to the checked resource. I used an activity log to avoid authentication. Thanks!